# Verifying kernel modules using a list of hashes

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I'm interested in preventing replay attacks on kernel module verification. I feel that using a list of hashes of kernel modules would be better for this than using digital signatures. My Motorola phone uses a list of hashes instead of digital signatures to verify kernel modules. Obviously, there would have to be some way to prevent modification to these values, perhaps by having a hash of the list or the list itself loaded into the kernel during boot time. Are there any hash-based verification methods for kernel modules like this out there?